# Measuring radius vs diameter for a circular ring?

Tags: experimental-physics, experimental-technique

Consider an experiment where I have to measure the radius of a circular ring diffraction (or interference) pattern (think Newton's rings).

It is advised to measure the diameter and then divide it by half instead of directly measuring the radius.

One reason for this could be due to the fact that it is difficult to pinpoint the center of the circle.

But is it better to measure the diameter if I know the position of the center with high accuracy?

Consider that I know the position of the center with as much confidence as I know the position of the circumference points. If my measuring device (let's say a Vernier caliper) adds an error of 0.02mm then if the true value of the radius for 5mm, I'll measure $5 mm\pm0.02mm$ whereas if I had measured the diameter I would have measured the value as $10mm\pm0.02mm$ and dividing by two would give me $5mm\pm0.01mm$, so it seems (if I not doing something wrong) that measuring the diameter is a better choice even if I know the center properly.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You would want to factor in error in aligning the calipers with the center. Knowing the position of the center and aligning to it are two different things.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. Imagine if you could magically expand the size of a paperclip to 5x before making a measurement, then shrink it back down again. Would you opt to measure the original version or the expanded version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.